# How do I make a route to a custom controller action in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, controller

I'm new to Rails, and a bit confused about routes:

I have a Devices controller:

```
#devices_controllers.rb
class DevicesController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @devices = Device.all
  end

  def show
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @device = Device.new
  end

  def create
    @device = Device.new(params[:device])
    if @device.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created device."
      redirect_to @device
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    if @device.update_attributes(params[:device])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated device."
      redirect_to @device
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @device = Device.find(params[:id])
    @device.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully destroyed device."
    redirect_to devices_url
  end

  def custom_action
    "Success"
  end
```

I'd like to access the "custom_action" action via a url like this:

```
http://foo.bar/devices/custom_action
```

I've added this line to my routes.rb file:

```
match 'devices/custom_action' => 'devices#custom_action'
```

However, when I try the URL in the browser, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in DevicesController#show

Couldn't find Device with ID=custom_action
```

It seems to be going to #show action instead of #custom_action. If a user id is not supplied, and I go to `http://foo.bar/devices/custom_action`,  I'd like it to go #custom_action.

I've read [Rails Routing from the Outside](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), but still can't still seem to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem may be because of the order in which you have defined your routes.

I suspect you have `resources :devices` in your `routes.rb`. In addition, I suspect you have defined your custom route **after** this. If you type `rake routes` into your console/terminal, you will see that there is already a route defined for the following pattern:

```
GET     /devices/:id
```

This route is a product of `resources :devices`, which is taking precedence over your custom route. Referring back to the Edge Guides, specifically in [1.1. Connecting URLs to Code](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#connecting-urls-to-code), it states that the request will be dispatched to the ***first*** matching route. So a simple fix would be to define your custom route before `resources :devices`.

Comment: Thanks John, I do have `resources :devices` before my custom route in the `routes.rb` file. I just moved the custom route so that it's above `resources :devices` and now it's working. Thanks!!

Comment: No prob. Glad I could help. =)